# The device, \Device\Harddisk1\D, has a bad block

Tags: bad-sectors, scan-disk

I got this error when I did my scan disk ( with the option to fix the error) on an external hard disk.

And here's the event log:

```
Checking file system on F:
Volume label is New Volume.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x1f60417000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x1f60417000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x1f60417000 for 0x1000 bytes.
The multi-sector header signature for VCN 0x5 of index $I30
in file 0x759a is incorrect.
78 01 09 00 b0 25 6b 02 87 f0 73 08 00 00 00 00  x. ..%k.‡.s.....
04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 a8 07 00 00  ........(...¨...
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30106.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x759a is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 30106.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0x18 is invalid.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ................
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ........
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
Sorting index $I30 in file 30106.
Cleaning up minor inconsistencies on the drive.
CHKDSK is recovering lost files.
Recovering orphaned file change.log (30132) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079807.lck (35315) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079822.lck (35333) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079824.lck (35338) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079799.lck (35339) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079800.lck (35342) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079801.lck (35343) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079802.lck (35344) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079803.lck (35345) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079811.lck (35346) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079804.lck (35347) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079805.lck (35348) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079838.lck (35349) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079816.lck (35351) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079817.lck (35352) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079818.lck (35353) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079819.lck (35354) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079820.lck (35355) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079825.lck (35356) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079823.lck (35357) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079826.lck (35360) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079827.lck (35361) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079828.lck (35362) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079829.lck (35363) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079830.lck (35364) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079831.lck (35365) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079832.lck (35366) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079833.lck (35367) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079834.lck (35368) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079839.lck (35369) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079835.lck (35370) into directory file 30106.
Recovering orphaned file A0079836.lck (35371) into directory file 30106.
Cleaning up 6 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 6 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 6 unused security descriptors.
CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)...
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x13bebba000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x13bebc5000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x13bec86000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x13bec94000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x13bed55000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x13bed62000 for 0x1000 bytes.
```

Does this mean that the hard disk is going to die? Or can it be due to other issues, such as the poor casing connection (*for it's an external hard disk wrapped in a casing*)?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that the hard disk is
>   going to die?

while I have seen hard drives working for years despite bad sectors, I wouldn't trust it with important data (at least not without an appropriate backup strategy).

> Or can it be due to other issues, such
>   as the poor casing connection (for
>   it's an external hard disk wrapped in
>   a casing)?

remove the drive from the enclosure and run a surface test again on an internal controller.

other than that, I can only recommend [**Hard Drive Regenerator**](http://www.dposoft.net/), a unique program for regeneration of physically damaged hard disk drives. of course the chances of recovery depend on the severeness of the damage but it saved my bacon on numerous occasions.

Answer (score 0):

The utility [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) contains some unique technology that can resuscitate bad hard disk sectors. It costs $89 but comes with Satisfaction Guaranteed refund. From the web page:

> SpinRite v6.0 recognizes and operates
>   on ALL file systems. It can even be
>   used to repair and recover Apple
>   Macintosh and Tivo hard drives by
>   temporarily moving them into an
>   Intel-based PC. It can also be used to
>   check the health of drives that have
>   not yet been formatted.

Comment: "All"? Let's see how it recognizes BeFS.

Comment: Yes, it's really all, since it reads/writes the disk directly and doesn't care about its format. It comes as a boot cd/diskette.

Comment: Who dared to downvote the wonderful SpinRite ? Come out and show yourself.